# Git clone all but one file or folder, possible?

Tags: git, git-clone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to clone a git repository’s sub-directory only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only)

Is it possible to clone a repository but some files?

Let's say I don't want to clone the `example` folder, because anyway I'll delete it after.

Comment: No. You could stop including example via git ignore OR you could use a hook to auto delete example each time you clone. But genetically there is no easy command for this as it violates the very concept of DVCS

Comment: @svnpenn, thanks for the link, I didn't find anything on my previous researchs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer - No.
Git clone will always clone the complete file structure.

If you want to minimise the amount of data over the network you can use
`git clone --depth 1`.

To achieve what you are asking for:

```
mkdir repo
cd repo
git init
git remote add -f origin $URL
git config core.sparseCheckout true
echo '$DIRNAME' >> .git/info/sparse-checkout # Do this for every directory you want.
git fetch
git checkout $BRANCH # Typically master
```

But I think that in your case, it is probably easier to just remove the `examples` directory.