# how to restore head after git clone? tried searching everywhere

Tags: git, gitlab, git-bash, git-clone

Here is the error message on git clone:

```sh
...
Receiving objects: 100% (8122401/8122401), 3.12 GiB | 3.31 MiB/s, done.  
Resolving deltas: 100% (6746605/6746605), done.

error: invalid path 'drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvkm/subdev/i2c/aux.c'

fatal: unable to checkout working tree warning:  
Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.

You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status' and 
retry with 'git restore --source-HEAD :/ "
```

As seen in:

[image: this is the screen shot of the git-bash when I got stuck]

How can I make the clone proceed?

Comment: please prefer adding some code in your post rather than a screenshot). Moreover, you didn't even provide the command you launched...

Comment: thanks..and sorry I'm new here and learning.. @St3an

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in "[Cloning succeded but checkout failed due to invalid path. What is the path problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61616948/6309)", [Windows cannot handle any file named AUX](https://www.howtogeek.com/fyi/windows-10-still-wont-let-you-use-these-file-names-reserved-in-1974/).

I suspect this is the issue here, considering your output:

```
error: invalid path 'drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvkm/subdev/i2c/aux.c'
```

I would recommend to:

- initialize an empty repository locally
- add the remote repository as `origin`
- set the local repo as sparse-checkout
- add '`drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvkm/subdev/i2c/aux.c`' to .git/info/sparse-checkout
- `git fetch`

See "[Git clone all but one file or folder, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14701421/6309)" as an example.

Answer (score 1):

> https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/linux/issues/111

"aux" is a reserved keyword in windows.
(windows doesn't allow file/folder name creation with "aux")

you can do this

```
git config core.protectNTFS false
git reset --hard HEAD
```